# How to sanitize and validate contact form for printing in screen and sending by email

Tags: php, html, forms, security, validation

I would like to know whether these precautions are enough.

I have an html form like this in my `index.php`:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <select name="Alimento">
        <option value="someValue">An option</option>
    </select>
    Nombre*:<?php echo $error['name'];?><br /><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><br />
    Mail*:<?php echo $error['mail'];?><br /><input type="text" name="mail" value="<?php echo $mail; ?>"/><br />
    <input id="botonComprar" type="image" src="img/comprar.png" name="submit" width="126" height="42">
</form>
```

Now on the top of the file I have:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $alimento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Alimento', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fname', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $mail    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    if($name == '') {
        $error['name'] = '<span class="errorMsg"> Ingrese su nombre</span>';

    }
    if($mail == '') {
        $error['mail'] = '<span class="errorMsg"> Ingrese su mail</span>';
    }
    if($phone == '') {
        $error['phone'] = '<span class="errorMsg"> Ingrese su tel&eacute;fono</span>';
    }
...
```

I later do:

```
if(empty($error)){
    mail($mail, $subject, $alimento, $headers);
}
```

This is of course simplified but it shows the gist of it.

So my questions are:

- Is there any big vulnerability I've overlooked in my code?
- Are the variables safe to echo as as values in the form?

  - I did the above to avoid the loss of filled in inputs, is this approach correct?
- Is the email properly validated? Is there any way the mail function could be exploited?
- Should I have used `htmlspecialchars` for `$alimento` and `$name`?

  - Is there any reason to use other email verification techniques?

Comment: Most of the code was made with the help of many kind users of the [PHP chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) so thanks to them!

Comment: If the form is public it could be used to send spam because a user could put in any email address and the script will send it anywhere.

Comment: @Cfreak it is in fact public,is there any way around this that is not with captcha? I don't think that is really an option...

Comment: overkill, understand the issues don;t just through every function at every variable.

Comment: @Dagon could you explain further? this is exactly why I posted the question to get a better understanding of the issue. As far I see it I am sanitizing the user imput because I will print it to screen and insert it in a mail (that might not be plain text), I'm also validating the email because if not the user could send thousands of emails at a time for example, what am I overdoing?

Comment: @Trufa the problem is that there's no detectable difference between a spam submission and a regular one. The question isn't "does this text contain HTML tags" or "is this address formatted correctly," it's "is this person entering their own email address or someone else's," and not even a human can tell that. Captchas aren't really a form of validation -- they still can't tell whether an individual response is legitimate. But they'd stop spammers from using your page as an open sendmail gateway. There are probably other ways to do that as well, (e.g., checking IPs) but I'm not an expert.

Comment: @Trufa - without really understanding the purpose of your form it's hard to say but generally if the email address comes from some other source that you control (like a database) that is much safer than it being entered from the user input.

Comment: @Cfreak the form is just simple public contact form where I ask users to select an option, put their names, email and phones and I send them a confirmation email and an email to myself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any big vulnerability I've overlooked in my code?

There are plenty of XSS holes here. Notably, `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` is a reflective XSS attack vector (possibly exploitable in conjunction with social engineering).

Furthermore, in  `mail($mail, $subject, $alimento, $headers);`, if the `$headers` is provided based on user input, you may find yourself vulnerable to [remote code execution](https://exploitbox.io/paper/Pwning-PHP-Mail-Function-For-Fun-And-RCE.html).

> Should I have used `htmlspecialchars` for `$alimento` and `$name`?

Yes, with `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5` instead of the default, on output rather than on input.